# How to get selected value from ng-option inside an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I loop through the questions in a questionnaire:

```
for (var j = 0; j < s.Questions.length; j++) {
    var q = s.Questions[j];
    var aq = datacontext.getAnsweredQuestion(propertySurvey.ID, q.ID);
    if (q.QuestionType === 'SingleAnswer') {
        q.dropdown = true;
        q.selectedOption = aq.ActualAnswers.length > 0 ?
                           aq.ActualAnswers[0].AnswerID : null;
        q.optionChanged = function () {
            var debug = q.selectedOption; //ERROR - this is undefined
            aq.toggleAnswer(q.selectedOption);
        }
    }
    //etc
}
```

In my view I also loop through the questions:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="q in s.Questions">
    <div class="item item-divider">{{q.Text}}</div>
    <div class="item" ng-if="q.dropdown">
        <select ng-model="q.selectedOption"
                ng-options="va.AnswerID as va.Text for va in q.ValidAnswers"
                ng-change="q.optionChanged()">
            <option>--Select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When viewed in the browser, the correct `selectedOption` is displayed, and the `q.optionChanged()` function is called. But inside that function, `q.selectedOption` is undefined

**EDIT**
This function appears to work. But I can't explain why!

```
q.optionChanged = function () {
    var debug = q.selectedOption;
    var answerid = this.selectedOption;
    aq.toggleAnswer(answerid);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are creating a function with closure inside a loop, which causes this unintuitive behavior. Read: [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)

What ends up happening is that the inner function captures the last `q` in the loop, for which (for some reason, perhaps not shown in code here), `q.optionChanged` is `undefined`.

In contrast, `this` is bound to the right `q` as supplied by the expression in `ng-change="q.optionChanged()"`.

To fix, use a function generator to create a function for each loop iteration, like so:

```
for (var j = 0; j < s.Questions.length; j++) {
  var q = s.Questions[j];
  var aq = datacontext.getAnsweredQuestion(...);

  // ... 

  q.optionChanged = makeOptionChangeFn(q, aq)

  // ...

}

function makeOptionChangeFn(q, aq){
  return function(){
    aq.toggleAnswer(q.selectedOption);
  }
}
```

Using `this` would have worked if you only needed to reference the right `q`, but you also need `aq`, so a function generator is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

In order to auto select the option from the controller, the ng-model **must hold a reference to the array** item. Assign `q.selectedOption` the whole item from the `aq.ActualAnswers`. You will need to refactor your comprehension expression.

```
// in the controller
q.selectedOption = aq.ActualAnswers.length > 0 ?
                           aq.ActualAnswers[0] : null;

// in the view
ng-options="va as va.Text for va in q.ValidAnswers"
```

This has caused me pain in the past. Make sure you read the documentation carefully:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: The option is being auto-selected. But I can't get the value of the newly selected item in the `optionChanged` function. `ValidAnswers` and `ActualAnswers` are two separate arrays. I've tried the code as you've written, I think am binding the ng-model to an `ActualAnswer`, but binding the options to a `ValidAnswer`, and that means it no longer auto-selects. What I have discovered is that `this.selectedOption` in place of `q.selectedOption` appears to contain the value...